# Xamarin GraphQlHttpClient just Crashes

Tags: c#, http, xamarin, graphql

So i created a Console Api with Graphql and EntityFrameworkCore to administrate a database. Now i want to use that server for my Xamarin Android Backend, I'm using Xamarin Forms.
The problem is...When i try to make a http request to my server is just crashes... I put the same code on a console app and it works just fine...
Here is the code i tried in the console app :

```
  var client = new GraphQLHttpClient("http://localhost:5000/graphql");
  var response = await client.SendMutationAsync("a mutation query");
  var result = response.Data;
```

It works just fine!
here is the code in my Xamarin App

```
 m_client = new GraphQLHttpClient(GraphQlEndpoint);;
 var response = await m_client.SendMutationAsync("some mutation");
 var jsonResponse = response.Data;
```

The application just crashes on var response = await... . Also i tried with a simple HttpClient but the result is the same. And yes the methods are async tasks.
One more thing all this code that handles the GraphQl Requests is an a Class Library that I referenced in the project.
Can somebody help me with this issue? Thank you for your time!

Also the application does't catch any exception on try catch

Comment: do NOT use localhost - use the actual IP of your server

Comment: i don't have any host right now, i just started this project

Comment: your server is whatever machine that is running your services

Comment: hosted the server on my inet http://192.********:5000 but still the same result

Comment: have you verified (using the device/simulator browser) that you can connect to that IP/port?  Have you checked for firewall settings?  Have you tried to trap the exception that causes the crash?

Comment: yeap, yeap annnnd yeap :( I'm really sad i can't find any solution

Comment: also...on a simple console app the request works...but in xamarin just crashes

Comment: a console app is a COMPLETELY different environment than a mobile app.  What is the actual exception causing the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the issue...my task was of type

```
async Task< ResponseType >
```

to solve the issue i had to set the type to

```
async Task
```

Here is the reason in detail : https://fluentbytes.com/how-to-solve-sporadic-crash-in-xamarin-app-with-async-and-await/.
 Thank you for your time! That was the most tricky bug i ever had.